# How to make a beer which is quickly ready to drink

Tags: recipe

I guess anyone doing beer is impatient to taste his "creation", and I sometimes have less patience than average.

What beer (I prefer ale) could I brew to have it ready to drink as soon as possilbe?

Comment: "triplicate": http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1566/brewing-with-a-deadline and http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3803/can-a-good-beer-be-ready-in-one-week?rq=1

Comment: heres another

http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7630/what-are-the-quickest-styles-from-grain-to-glass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Stick to low OG.  1.035 - 1.045
- Make sure you have a healthy fermentation:  Right amount of healthy yeast, nutrients, proper temperature, aeration, etc.
- To clear the yeast quickly after fermentation, you might try clarifiers, cold crashing or filtering